# php loop within mysqli loop

Tags: php, loops, mysqli

I have one mysql table which contains 2 columns and looks like this...

```
-------------------------------------------
| sku                 | superseded_sku    |
+---------------------+-------------------+
| part1               | part2             |
| part2               | part3             |
| part3               | part4             |
| part5               | part6             |
| part6               | part7             |
```

the table basically shows where products sold by a company have been replaced by something newer. My task is to reshape the table to resemble the following...

```
-------------------------------------------
| sku                 | superseded_sku    |
+---------------------+-------------------+
| part1               | part4             |
| part2               | part4             |
| part3               | part4             |
| part5               | part7             |
| part6               | part7             |
```

Thus eradicating the need to shuffle through the list to find the current replacement.

I have written the following which has one basic downfall in that if a product had been replaced more times that I have allowed for in my code then it wouldn't look that far. I have tried many times to include a while loop, a do {} while loop and a foreach loop but so far I've failed massively.

Here's my code as it stands

```
<?php    
    // Error reporting on

    ini_set("display_errors", 1);
    ini_set("error_reporting", E_ALL);

    // variables

    // Page variable
    $P = $_REQUEST["p"];

    // variables for latest BritPart list

    $dbhost = 'localhost';
    $dbuser = 'userame';
    $dbpass = 'password';
    $dbselect = 'superseded';

    $mysqli = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbselect);
    if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
        die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
        . mysqli_connect_error());
        }

    // Start throwing data about  
    $compare = "SELECT * FROM mar15 ORDER BY sku";

    echo "<h3 style=\"text-align: center;\">Supersedes Tables</h3>
    <div class=\"output\" style=\"width: 940px;\">
    <table cellspacing=\"0\" class=\"db-table\" style=\"width: 940px; border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0\"><thead><tr>
    <th width=\"398\">sku</th>
    <th width=\"270\">superseded_sku</th>
    <th width=\"270\">supersede_length</th>
    </tr></thead>
    <tbody>";

    if ($result = mysqli_query($mysqli,"$compare")) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

            $sku = $row['sku'];
            $ss1 = $row['superseded_sku'];
            $ssl = "1";

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------
    // I want to loop through this section until it doesn't find a match
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------

            $query1 = "SELECT superseded_sku FROM mar15 WHERE sku = \"$ss1\"";
                if ($result1 = mysqli_query($mysqli,"$query1")) {
                    while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) {
                        $ss2 = $row1['superseded_sku'];
                        if($ss2 != $ss1) {
                            $ssl++;
                            $ss1 = $ss2;
                        }
                    }
                }

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------
    // Instead I've done this as I don't know how to do what I want
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------

            $query1 = "SELECT superseded_sku FROM mar15 WHERE sku = \"$ss1\"";
                if ($result1 = mysqli_query($mysqli,"$query1")) {
                    while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) {
                        $ss2 = $row1['superseded_sku'];
                        if($ss2 != $ss1) {
                            $ssl++;
                            $ss1 = $ss2;
                        }
                    }
                }

            $query1 = "SELECT superseded_sku FROM mar15 WHERE sku = \"$ss1\"";
                if ($result1 = mysqli_query($mysqli,"$query1")) {
                    while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) {
                        $ss2 = $row1['superseded_sku'];
                        if($ss2 != $ss1) {
                            $ssl++;
                            $ss1 = $ss2;
                        }
                    }
                }

            $query1 = "SELECT superseded_sku FROM mar15 WHERE sku = \"$ss1\"";
                if ($result1 = mysqli_query($mysqli,"$query1")) {
                    while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) {
                        $ss2 = $row1['superseded_sku'];
                        if($ss2 != $ss1) {
                            $ssl++;
                            $ss1 = $ss2;
                        }
                    }
                }

            $query1 = "SELECT superseded_sku FROM mar15 WHERE sku = \"$ss1\"";
                if ($result1 = mysqli_query($mysqli,"$query1")) {
                    while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) {
                        $ss2 = $row1['superseded_sku'];
                        if($ss2 != $ss1) {
                            $ssl++;
                            $ss1 = $ss2;
                        }
                    }
                }

            $query1 = "SELECT superseded_sku FROM mar15 WHERE sku = \"$ss1\"";
                if ($result1 = mysqli_query($mysqli,"$query1")) {
                    while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) {
                        $ss2 = $row1['superseded_sku'];
                        if($ss2 != $ss1) {
                            $ssl++;
                            $ss1 = $ss2;
                        }
                    }
                }

            $query1 = "SELECT superseded_sku FROM mar15 WHERE sku = \"$ss1\"";
                if ($result1 = mysqli_query($mysqli,"$query1")) {
                    while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) {
                        $ss2 = $row1['superseded_sku'];
                        if($ss2 != $ss1) {
                            $ssl++;
                            $ss1 = $ss2;
                        }
                    }
                }

            $query1 = "SELECT superseded_sku FROM mar15 WHERE sku = \"$ss1\"";
                if ($result1 = mysqli_query($mysqli,"$query1")) {
                    while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) {
                        $ss2 = $row1['superseded_sku'];
                        if($ss2 != $ss1) {
                            $ssl++;
                            $ss1 = $ss2;
                        }
                    }
                }

            $query1 = "SELECT superseded_sku FROM mar15 WHERE sku = \"$ss1\"";
                if ($result1 = mysqli_query($mysqli,"$query1")) {
                    while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) {
                        $ss2 = $row1['superseded_sku'];
                        if($ss2 != $ss1) {
                            $ssl++;
                            $ss1 = $ss2;
                        }
                    }
                }

            $query1 = "SELECT superseded_sku FROM mar15 WHERE sku = \"$ss1\"";
                if ($result1 = mysqli_query($mysqli,"$query1")) {
                    while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) {
                        $ss2 = $row1['superseded_sku'];
                        if($ss2 != $ss1) {
                            $ssl++;
                            $ss1 = $ss2;
                        }
                    }
                }

            $query1 = "SELECT superseded_sku FROM mar15 WHERE sku = \"$ss1\"";
                if ($result1 = mysqli_query($mysqli,"$query1")) {
                    while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) {
                        $ss2 = $row1['superseded_sku'];
                        if($ss2 != $ss1) {
                            $ssl++;
                            $ss1 = $ss2;
                        }
                    }
                }

            $query1 = "SELECT superseded_sku FROM mar15 WHERE sku = \"$ss1\"";
                if ($result1 = mysqli_query($mysqli,"$query1")) {
                    while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) {
                        $ss2 = $row1['superseded_sku'];
                        if($ss2 != $ss1) {
                            $ssl++;
                            $ss1 = $ss2;
                        }
                    }
                }

            $query1 = "SELECT superseded_sku FROM mar15 WHERE sku = \"$ss1\"";
                if ($result1 = mysqli_query($mysqli,"$query1")) {
                    while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) {
                        $ss2 = $row1['superseded_sku'];
                        if($ss2 != $ss1) {
                            $ssl++;
                            $ss1 = $ss2;
                        }
                    }
                }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        echo "<tr";
            if($ssl > 1) {
                echo " style=\"background: #ff0;\"";
            }
        echo ">
                <td width=\"398\">$sku</td>
                <td width=\"270\">$ss1</td>
                <td width=\"270\">$ssl</td>
                </tr>";
    }
    $result->close();
    }
    echo "</tr></tbody></table><a href=\"#\" class=\"export linkbutton\" style=\"margin: 10px 0 0 0; display: block; text-align: center;\">Export CSV</a></div>";

    mysqli_close($mysqli);

?>
```

You can see that I've commented where I want a loop to sit, I've no idea how to make one work however, my redneck methods work but I'm not happy with them and wish to improve my skills. Those aren't my real user/pass before anybody asks.

Comment: you should use a single query using a `join`. anytime you have nested queries and the inner query uses data from the outer query, a join will almost always be more efficient. one single query, instead of 1+n queries. Oh, and try to use better variable names. `ss1` and `ssl` are visually VERY confusing...

Comment: @MarcB I tried using a JOIN but it resulted in less rows being returned than I originally had which doesn't solve the problem. Unless you have a better way of writing the query than I did.

`SELECT x.sku, x.superseded_sku
FROM mar15 x
JOIN mar15 y ON y.sku = x.superseded_sku`

Comment: Maybe you want a LEFT JOIN. Not sure what your desired output is.

Comment: In any case you would be better off figuring out the proper query to get the desired output (its possible), rather than your current approach

Comment: @dan08 I tried and tried to get it done with 1 query but to no avail. This method gives me the correct output as stated above, the list is ~2,500 products. Using a JOIN I wind up with 436 products which isn't the desired result, I require an output with all products still listed but each superseded_sku will be the latest one. EG. If currently A is replaced by B but that is replaced by C and that by D then A would point to D, and so would B and C missing out the middle-man on each product. This goes 6 or 7 levels deep in some instances however, hence my wanting a loop.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Normally, I wouldn't advocate having database queries inside loops; it is inefficient and can cause excessive load on your database server.

That said, I don't see much alternative unless you can refactor your data model. What you have is a parent/child relationship within a single table ("superseded_sku" references a child record of the same table). This is bad for what you are trying to do as you never know beforehand if the child record has any children of it's own.

Assuming refactoring is not feasible, you want to run the query, check if there are matching records, update the query and repeat until there are no more records.

Try something like this...

```
// get initial result set (don't forget to escape your variables)
$query = "SELECT superseded_sku FROM mar15 WHERE sku = '" .
        mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $ss1) . "'";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);

// loop while we have results
while(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    // double check the row is valid
    if (empty($row["superseded_sku"])) {
        break;
    }
    $ss1 = $row["superseded_sku"];

    // run the query again to check for further superseded skus
    $query = "SELECT superseded_sku FROM mar15 WHERE sku = '" .
        mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $ss1) . "'";
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
}
```

I would seriously advise against using this approach as a long term measure, as it does not scale well at all. You will almost certainly encounter server resource issues or timeouts, especially if your product list continues growing. You will need to give some thought to refactoring the data if this is something you plan to use in the future.

Comment: Technically the data should do the opposite month by month and shrink, this job hasn't been done literally ever before. I am estimating that in the future it would only go 2 steps deep but can't be 100% sure (parts can be superseded 3 or 4 times monthly). Based upon this it does make my life easier as this is the way that the data is supplied, refactoring would simply add extra man-hours to the job each month, effectively making the job a manual task.

Thank you for that one sir.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any update statements so I guess that is not the problem.

I also don't know if a loop is the most efficient solution, but if you are going to loop, you want to loop until there are no elements in the `superseded_sku` column that also exist in the `sku` column.

That is easy to check with a nested select statement, something like:

```
SELECT superseded_sku
FROM mar15
WHERE superseded_sku IN (
  SELECT DISTINCT sku FROM mar15
)
```

This query will get you all elements in the `superseded_sku` column that have a counterpart in the `sku` column / that need to be replaced.

So while this sql statement returns more than 0 rows, you need to make more replacements.

You could probably take this a step further and combine it with your `UPDATE` statement as well but this should get you started.

Comment: I don't intend on using an UPDATE statement, the resulting table is rendered in html, the link at the bottom of the table will export it as a csv when we need it. The idea here is that I can replace the table form time to time as our already huge (30,000+) product list grows. I simply need a way of making it dig as deep as it can for each row returned.