# Executing mysqli prepared statment within while loop that's executing another mysqli prepared statment

Tags: php, mysqli, bindparam

I have one mysql table which contains information of all products except their photos and looks like this :

watchID |  watch_serial | ....> and so on

Then I have my product picture table looks like this :

picID | name_prod | watch_serial | ....> and so on

the relation key between these 2 tables is watch_serial

Each watch from the first table may have several pictures in the 2nd table. So to fetch all pictures related to each watch_serial I must put one mysqli SELECT query with in the other one as following :

```
    $watchQ = "SELECT `watch_serial` FROM `watch` ";
    $watchSTMT= $db->prepare($watchQ); 
    $watchSTMT->execute();
    $watchSTMT->bind_result($watch_serial );
    while ( $watchSTMT->fetch()){

        echo $wa_serial."<br>"; 


    $prodSEARCHq = "SELECT `name_prod` FROM ppic WHERE pserial = ?";
    $prodSEARCHstms= $db->prepare($prodSEARCHq);  
    $prodSEARCHstms->bind_param("s",$watch_serial);
    $prodSEARCHstms->execute();
    $prodSEARCHstms->bind_result($name_prod);
    while ($prodSEARCHstms->fetch()){

        echo $name_prod;




    }
    $prodSEARCHstms->close();
    }
```

above queries will echo the result properly if I separate them and run them separately but if I mix the loops as you see above I will get the following error  :

RAAA0009L19B

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/watche.php:7535 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/watche.php on line 7535

which would be on the following line :

```
    $prodSEARCHstms->bind_param("s",$watch_serial);
```

I have made sure that bind_param conditions all are set correctly.

I have checked the solutions provided here: [Executing mysqli prepared statment within while loop that's within another while loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32552042/executing-mysqli-prepared-statment-within-while-loop-thats-within-another-while)

and [php loop within mysqli loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29541973/php-loop-within-mysqli-loop)

Unfortunately, I'm still getting the same error.

Is this happening because of running a query within a loop of fetching another query? I don't see any other ways around to get the searching key from the first query rather than my own code, please help me out as I have tried many similar ways with the same Fatal error

Comment: You are supposed not to "check" the solution but actually *implement* it in your code

Comment: what do you mean? why you closed the question? I have checked those solutions too. I am still having the error. I have shared 2 other links that provided a solution just like your link. have you read all that I wrote there ????

Comment: It would be easier for you to start using PDO instead of mysqli. You need to fetch the result from the statement. See examples at https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli